# Show array values in php loop by sort

Tags: php, arrays, loops, while-loop

How i can show one array in each loop? for example with this code i can show random color codes for each loop, but i need to show order by DESC:

```
$Colors = array('111', '222', '333', '444', '555');

$i = 1;

while($i <= $Limit){
  echo "Color Code:". $Colors[array_rand($Colors)]."<br>";
$i++;
}
```

and this is my result and problem:

```
Color Code:333
Color Code:333
Color Code:444
Color Code:111
Color Code:555
Color Code:222
Color Code:111
Color Code:222
Color Code:555
Color Code:222
Color Code:333
Color Code:444
```

how i can show the result like this:

```
Color Code:111
Color Code:222
Color Code:333
Color Code:444
Color Code:555
Color Code:111
Color Code:222
Color Code:333
Color Code:444
Color Code:555
Color Code:111
Color Code:222
...
```

Comment: What in the world does this code do?

Comment: You are picking random entries from a sequential array and want to list them sequentially?

Comment: Not Random, sequentially

Comment: You shown us two different arrays of which one is undefined here, and the other one isn't used...

Comment: The obvious followup question is why are you randomizing them initially then?

Comment: Assuming `$input` is actually `$Colors`, just loop through `$Colors`, it is already sorted.

Comment: @Explosion Pills i just wrote a example!

Comment: @Maciej Sz i fixed the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while($i <= $Limit){
    echo "Color Code:". $input[$i % count($input)]."<br>";
    $i++;
}
```

Or substitute `$input` for `$Colors` depending upon what the variable is actually called.

Comment: @MaciejSz you could move `count` outside the loop; technically more efficient but I don't think it would be noticeable for 20 items.

Comment: Not until two years after, when unnoticeably that array grow to 2M items... I'm just saying: it should be automatic.

Comment: @Explosion Pills thank you my friend

Comment: @MaciejSz `time php -r '$x = array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"); $i = 0; $limit = 2000000; while ($i <= $limit) { count($x); $i++; }'` -- takes about 32 MS on my machine.

Comment: Really? It took 600ms on my i7. With the count outside the loop it took 300ms. 50% bonus? I'm in.

Comment: Php 5.2 - 300ms; PHP 5.4 - 600ms; PHP 5.5 - 1s (!) What do you have there? Like 4 Xeons?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$Colors = array('222', '111', '333', '555', '444');
sort($Colors);

for($i = 0; $i < count($Colors); $i++)
{
   printf("Color code: %s <br />", $Colors[$i]);
}
?>
```

Comment: It's a small static array in a very simplistic example, not sure how thread-safety would really be an issue here. The only problem I see would be if they are pushing values into the array they are iterating over, which they shouldn't be and are not in their question.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick!

```
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($Colors); $i++){
  echo "Color Code:". $Colors[$i]."<br>";
}
```